# Prove that a serie of matrices converges to $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

I've been struggling with this problem for a while I cannot find the solution, hope you can help me.

Prove that the series $(I + A + A^2 + ...)$ converges if $\begin{Vmatrix}B\end{Vmatrix} < 1$, where $B = PAP^{-1}$. What is the implication of this result?, Construct a simple example to see usefulness of the result in practical computations.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem to me. What are your own thoughts on the subject? What did you try? What worked, what did not?

Comment: What is $P$ in the expression for $B$? Is it any invertible matrix?

Comment: The headline seems a bit misleading....try the Neumann series, which is an extension of the geometrical series on operators...

Comment: I would like to prove that $A^{\mathrm T}A$ is equal to $B^{\mathrm T}B$ since there is a link between both of them (norm 2 use this matrix product).

Answer (score 0):

Couple of tips which probably has nothing to do with your problem or may be it has

- From real analysis, for any variable $x$ with $|x|<1$, $(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2\dots$. This is not directly extendable to matrices though.
- $||A||_2=\sigma_1(A)=\sqrt{\lambda_{max}(A^TA)}$
- $\det(PQP^{-1}-\lambda I)=\det(Q-\lambda I)$ for any invertible $P$ and matrix $Q$.
- If $B= PAP^{-1}$, then $B^n = PA^{n}P^{-1}$